# C# TCP Server using infinite Loop unexpectedly closes

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, memory, tcp

I am currently developing a C# TCP Server application for my game. The Server functions perfectly for a long period of time, closes however unexpectedly after about a day or 2 of running. I've furthermore printed the console output to a file, which I checked after the application closed, and there were no errors, or at least none were printed. The Code for the server is the following :

```
class Program
{
    private static Thread consoleThread;
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        //To get the output in a file
        
        FileStream filestream = new FileStream("out.txt", FileMode.Create);
        var streamwriter = new StreamWriter(filestream);
        streamwriter.AutoFlush = true;
        Console.SetOut(streamwriter);
        Console.SetError(streamwriter);
        

        InitializeConsoleThread();
        ServerHandleData.InitializePacketListener();
        ServerTCP.InitializeServer();
    }
    private static void InitializeConsoleThread()
    {
        consoleThread = new Thread(ConsoleLoop);
        consoleThread.Name = "ConsoleThread";
        consoleThread.Start();
    }
    private static void ConsoleLoop()
    {
        while (true)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

The TCP Clients are handled with the following async methods :

```
private static void InitializeServerSocket()
    {
        ServerSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8080);
        ServerSocket.Start();
        ServerSocket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnectCallback, null); //Once we get a connection, ClientConnectCallback is called
    }
    private static void ClientConnectCallback(IAsyncResult result)
    {
        TcpClient tempClient = ServerSocket.EndAcceptTcpClient(result); //Accepts the connection and creates its corresponding TcpClient
        ServerSocket.BeginAcceptTcpClient(ClientConnectCallback, null); //Open the connection again for other players

        string[] IPs = tempClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString().Split(':');
        if(IPDictionary.TryGetValue(IPs[0], out ClientObject C))
        {
            C.Socket = tempClient;

            C.Socket.NoDelay = true;
            C.Socket.ReceiveBufferSize = 4096;
            C.Socket.SendBufferSize = 4096;

            C.ReceiveBuffer = new byte[4096];
            C.myStream = C.Socket.GetStream();

            C.IP = tempClient.Client.RemoteEndPoint.ToString();
            C.myStream.BeginRead(C.ReceiveBuffer, 0, C.Socket.ReceiveBufferSize, C.ReceiveCallback, null);

            PACKET_SendMessage(C.ConnectionID, "CheckIP", 0, IPs[0]);

            Console.WriteLine("Connection incoming from {0}", C.IP);
            return;
        }           
        Random ran = new Random();
        int curID = ran.Next();     //random signed int
        while (curID == 0 || ClientObjects.ContainsKey(curID)) { curID = ran.Next(); }

        ClientObjects[curID] = new ClientObject(tempClient, curID);
        TempPlayers[curID] = new TempPlayer();
    }
```

which are called in the Program class with the initializeServer methods.
The Server functions well for a while and then suddenly closes, seemingly without any reason. The only cause I could find while searching on the internet is that the program eventually runs out of memory and just closes. Wouldn't however the garbage collector integrated in C# prevent such a thing ? Thank you all for your help in advance, I hope I made the question as direct and as clear as possible. Furthermore, if there are any other ways to improve these snippets of code, please do tell.

Comment: You can use task manager to watch memory usage.  Memory with TCP is only an issue when you are sending lots of packets quickly.  Check when app closes on both client and server using from cmd.exe >Netstat -a.  See if both client and server closes or if you have a Time Error.   You can use a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler and look for a [FIN] which indicates connection closes.  TCP retries and will close if a packet is not ACK.  TCP defaults are to send a packets 3 time at 5 seconds apart.  When a server gets backed up the ACK isn't sent and then connection closes.

Comment: I don't see any try-catch in there, so that might be the reason why no error messages appears in your log?

Comment: First,thank you both for your answers and time.@TobiasRaphaelDieckmann I added a try catch block to ClientConnectCallBack,I'll see if I get any errors this time.@jdweng Thank you for the tip with Netstat -a.One question though,my whole application closes after a day or 2,and this shouldn't be caused by a TCP connection closing, should it? I have a try catch block in my ClientObject class without a throw statement handling the reading from the TCP connection.That means that any exception should be caught,close the connection,and not lead to a crash.Sorry,i'm still a beginner at TCP Programming.